# ErrorProvider and Exception Handling in C#

Tags: c#, exception, errorprovider

What is the difference between Exception Handling and errorProvider in C#?

May i use Exception Handling like ErrorProvider....

Answer (score 2):

[ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx) is a WinForms user interface control for presenting error information to the user. [Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx) is a language feature for designing code to handle exceptions at run-time.

`ErrorProvider` might be used to provide details about a handled execption to the user. They're almost completely different and definitely not interchangable.

Answer (score 0):

ErrorProvider is part of System.Windows.Forms whereas Exception Handling is provided by the framework and exceptions ultimately derive from System.Exception.  The error provider is used by WinForms explicitly.  You use it to tell a user that a particular winforms element has an error associated with it.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx